# Can user share his contact information on Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion

Recently i came across this [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/111991/how-to-turn-on-block-or-panel-from-old-site-to-the-new-one) where OP is unable to resolve his issue related to migration of view. It seems off topic for me.

He offered bounty of 20$ and asked to share contact information so that one can resolve his issue.

Is contact sharing allowed in Stack Exchange ? Do we encourage questions like above ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can share your contact information in the about me section of your profile, which people can obviously use if you choose to do so.

Facilitating that connection is not what the site is for, though, so comments like the one you mentioned are inappropriate. I've deleted it.

Regarding the question you linked to - it looks on topic to me, if a little vague.

The other question (https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/112025/quick-job-for-experienced-drupal-guy-imoprting-data-from-view-to-new, now deleted) is certainly off topic

Answer (score 6):

To add what Clive said, offering money bounty is not in the spirit of Stack Exchange. If you see any user offering money, edit that part away from the question; it is something not strictly related to the question, and it should be removed.